Why indexes on ENUMs doesn't get applied?
I have the following query:
EXPLAIN SELECT *
   FROM transactions
  WHERE retry < 5
  ORDER BY id ASC
  LIMIT 100

//=> Output: 
id | select_type | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | transactions | NULL       | index | status,retry  | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 200  | 50.00    | Using where

As you can see, it's optimized enough and it scans just 200 rows. It gets executed in 0.004 sec.
But sadly when I add another AND on WHERE clause (which is a ENUM datatype) it gets much slower. See:
EXPLAIN SELECT *
   FROM transactions
  WHERE retry < 5
    AND status = 'failure'    # this added
  ORDER BY id ASC
  LIMIT 100

//=> Output: 
id | select_type | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys          | key      | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | transactions | NULL       | ref   | status,status_2,retry  | status_2 | 1       | const | 255260 | 50.00    | Using where

See? Just by adding AND status = 'failure' it took much slower, and it takes over 4 secs to get executed. Any idea how can I make it faster and more optimal?

Noted that, I have the following indexes:
transactions: INDEX(retry, status)
transactions: INDEX(status)
transactions: INDEX(retry)


Are you sure those two EXPLAINs were run on the same table? It doesn't make sense that an index-scan would estimate only 200 rows, but a ref (index lookup) would estimate 25k rows. Perhaps the index stats are severely out of sync with data.

Have you tried an index on (status, retry)? const before range

@user1191247 WOW ... It made it fucking fast, thanks.

Does this answer your question? Does Order of Fields of Multi-Column Index in MySQL Matter

Put any column(s) tested with = first in the INDEX.

Indexes, that are mainly BTrees structures, needs to have atomic values to perform. ENUMs, ARRAYs, ROWs datatype are not atomic, because they are compound of several values. An index on such a datatype does not have any sense because it will probably never been used...
That why tables are always preferable instead of such exotic non relational datatypes...
So transform the STATUS column into a reference table, put an index on the "status_label" column do a join and you will have performances !
